# SQL - Storing values that have dynamic properties and constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm not sure if what I'm attempting to do is simply incorrect/impossible or if there is an easier way and that I'm missing the point.

I'm using SQL Server 2012

What I would like to do is have a table that can store rows with values relating to stored properties in another table. Basically, key value pair. The thing is, I would like to determine which key values can be used by which entities.

For example,
I would like one table listing various companies, another to store 'files' created for each company - this is used to store historical information, another listing various production departments(stages in production), another listing production figures(KGs, Units, etc), and one listing the actual production capture against these figures for each month. There are also tables in place to show which production departments can use which production figures as well as which company has which production departments.

Some of the companies have the same stages in production as well as additional stages that the others don't.

These figures are captured on a monthly basis ONLY, so I have a table describing all the months of a year.

Each production department may have similar types of recordings to be captured, though they don't all have the same production readings.

Here's a link to a graphical representation of the table layouts:
http://tinypic.com/r/30a51mx/8
..

---

My end result is to auto-populate / update the table with newly added figures as the user enters this section of the program (by passing through the FileID), and to allow the user to edit this using a datagridview (or atleast select a value to be edited from the datagridview)

I will then need to write reports later on that will need to pivot on this information.

---

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Consider whether you really want to go down the EAV path. Is the nature of the data so variable that you have to do this? It really doesn't seem that way. There's nothing wrong with a table that has some sparsely populated columns.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll reconsider my approach. I have roughly about 10-15 stages to cater for, about 20 different figures across 3 companies. Would you reckon creating a table per stage as feasible, or creating 1 table with nullable fields a better approach as opposed to EAV in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For an effective DB design it is very important to understand, two major requirements:

1. ***Should the DB design be done keeping in mind the ease of use from application point of view or from efficient storage point of view.***

This point is by large decided keeping in mind following factors:

- **How much data are we going to store**, so we need to have some idea about cost of storage factoring redundancy. Good normalised DB reduces redundancy.
  Your DB is normalised very well, but is that really needed. Typically cost of storage is very less in today's time, and so if we can think of design which is slightly more redundant, it should be OK. Unless of course you plan to use Standard version of SQL server which has its own limitation in terms of DB size.
- **Is the data retrieval and update slow/fast?** The more normalised DB is more number JOINS are expected. In your case, if you want to return values for multiple properties, say n, in a single result, then you'd need to make **n joins** on the ProductionProperty table, which will essentially reduce query performance, and hence slow user experience. So unless your UI is not very demanding, and your users can live with small lag, go ahead with a normalised DB design.
- **ORM mismatch**- Since the relational database model and object model (assuming programming language follows OOPs concept) usually mismatch and they will heavily in a normalised scenario like this; you'll need to spend more hours coding through or troubleshooting scenarios which may require you to squirm in pain when making changes to either of these models. I suggest you use a good ORM framework to counter this and be more aware of the ORM mismatch scenarios.

  2. ***Will you have separate Reporting DB or Reporting tables?*** Basically this translates into is your DB an OLTP database or Reporting Database? If this DB is going to worked on heavily by Data entry persons day in and day out, normalised form should be suitable considering that Point #1 is satisfied. If however reporting is a major need, then de-normalised form should be preferred (which means that you do not need so many separate tables).

PS: Master data should be kept in table of its own.I can say Months definitely is a master data and so is UoM unless you plan to do CRUD on the UoM measures too. Also note that it hardly matters keeping month in separate table especially when same business logic/constraints can be enforced on columns in SQL.

Comment: I will be using a standard version so size will be a factor in the future, I agree with all your points though. From this I'm thinking that it may cause me more grief than it's worth and that I should possibly rethink my approach.